# Android Studion Build Tools Version

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, build-tools

How can I set the default build tools version in Android Studio? Everytime I make a new project I need to set it to an old version (default 23.0.0 rc1,
old 22.0.1) because of the error

```
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
> aidl is missing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file named `gradle.properties` in whatever directory applies:

- `/home/<username>/.gradle/` (Linux)
- `/Users/<username>/.gradle/` (Mac)
- `C:\Users\<username>\.gradle` (Windows)

Append:

```
systemProp.buildToolsVersion=22.0.1
```

For more details, see [Gradle DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/)、[Gradle user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html).

Answer (score 1):

right click on your app -> Open module settings. Set in the menu the 'Build Tools Version' to version 22.0.1.

If you don't want to do it always for every project try :
changing the Preferences - Go to File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle Project-level settings from 'Use local gradle distribution' to 'Use default gradle wrapper (recommended).

Comment: I know that, but i need to do it everytime. Is there any way to do this once for all future project?